# How to see how much time I have left for my current interactive SLURM session?

Tags: slurm

Or better, is there a way I can attach the time left to my command prompt? I just want to make sure that my current intersctive SLURM session does not abruptly end when I am running some processes.

Answer (score 4):

You can modify your `PS1` env variable like so:

```
export PS1="$PS1 \$(squeue -h -j $SLURM_JOBID -o %L) "
```

to have the time left printed after your usual prompt.

Comment: This will cause the terminal prompt messed up. Simply `echo "$(squeue -h -j $SLURM_JOBID -o %L)"`. BTW, rerun `./.bashrc` to restore your original shell prompt.